# Python abc inheritance with specified metaclass

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass, abc

What is the proper way of inheriting from ABC if class have metaclass specified?

Straightforward attempt

```
class KindMeta(type):
    ...

class Kind(ABC, metaclass=KindMeta):
    ...
```

resulted in `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`

Inheriting ABCMeta in KindMeta seems kind of wrong, because this `mcs` is also used to create nonabstract classes.

Creating custom ABC inherited from KindMeta sounds well neither.

Is there a better way of dealing with it? or which of the solutions is more pythonic and should be preferred?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to create a second metaclass, inheritng from both your orignal metaclass and the `abc.ABCMeta` and use that metaclass as the metaclass on the classes you want.

If your metaclass is correctly constructed, using `super()` calls in all (special) methods it implements, it as straightforward as:

```py
import abc 
...

class KindMeta(type):
    ...

class CombinedMeta(KindMeta, abc.ABCMeta):
    pass

class Kind(ABC, metaclass=CombinedMeta):
    ...
```

If your metaclass is not making use of  `super()`, but calling hardcoded `type` methods, you have to change it to do so.  For some methods like `__prepare__` and `__call__`, it makes sense to not call the correspondent 
 `super()` method depending on what you are doing, and I think there is no need to run the correspondent methods in `ABCMeta`. 
And, of course, that is only needed if you don't want or can't change the metaclass you already have, or if you want your metaclass to be used in other classes that are not using ABC -

Otherwise, you can just make your own metaclass inherit from `ABCMeta` itself - no need to create a third metaclass to combine both:

```py
import abc 
...

class KindMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
    ...
```

If, on the other hand, you are using the metaclass + class construction machinery of Python to create objects that are "not quite classes" (like for example the `zope.interface` package does to create interfaces), you have to decide (1) if it makes sense to use that along `abc.ABC` at all, and second, if the correspondent method in the ABCMeta have to be run (usually yes, if you need the functionality). In that case you have to customize your metaclass appropriately - which may include to force combining the classes with multiple-inheritance (even if you could just inherit from ABCMeta) to prevent it from calling `type.__new__` (if that is your intent):

```py
class KindMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, ns, **kw):
        cls = ExistingClassRegistry[name]
        return cls

class CombinedMeta(abc.ABCMeta, KindMeta):
    # note the reversed order - ABCMeta will run first
    # and call super().__new__ which runs KindMeta.__new__ and
    # does not forward to type.__new__  
    pass
```